# Angular 5 unit testing object in template causes [object ErrorEvent] thrown

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular5

I'm getting an error running Jasmine tests in Angular 5. It seems to be linked to the object bindings in the template file. If I have a binding 3 levels deep I get the following error

```
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

The error goes away when I change the template from

```
<p class="item__auth-name">{{shot.user.name}}</p>
```

to

```
<p class="item__auth-name">{{shot.user}}</p>
```

Here is my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { IShot } from '../../shared/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.scss']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  public shot: IShot;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shot = this.route.snapshot.data['shot'];
  }

}
```

And here is my spec file

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SafePipe } from '../../core/pipes/safe.pipe';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details.component';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

describe('DetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: DetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DetailsComponent>;
  let dataFromActivatedRoute = {
    id: 1
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DetailsComponent, SafePipe ]
    })
    .overrideComponent(DetailsComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [
          {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
             snapshot: {
              data: {
                shot: dataFromActivatedRoute
              }
            }
          }}
        ]
      }})
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
      });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Removing the fixture.detectChanges() in the spec file also removes the error but that's not fixing the problem. Does anyone have experience with this kind of behavior?

Comment: I think I just hadn't set up the mock ActivatedRoute data correctly. I needed to add any data that my template uses to the dummy data in the spec file.

Comment: Great you could solve your problem. Better put your solution in an answer and accept it so that others see your problem was resolved.